# Can I customize UIReferenceLibraryViewController's appearance and "Done" button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, uiviewcontroller

I'm using `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` to pop up a dictionary to define certain words in my application. It's a very bare-bones controller, and I'm calling it into a smaller view on my main view (akin to a sidebar) rather than with a `UINavigationController`. As a result, the "Done" button that it includes does nothing when I tap it.

Can I either hide, or customize the behaviour of this Done button?

Failing that, or alternatively, could I get the contents of the definition in some format or other (HTML, XML, NSData, etc.), to display in my own way?

I do have a third-party dictionary in my app already but the definitions it gives are kinda hit-and-miss, and I'd prefer to use the Apple ones if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience of a DMCA takedown notice from the dictionary provider, you cannot manipulate this view controller in any way. If you do, you are violating contracts and open yourself up to legal action.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation for that class should definitely state that more plainly.

Comment: @BenjaminMayo Hey Benjamin, do you, by any chance, remember who the dictionary provider is?

Comment: There's several around the world, but I got targeted by Enfour.

Comment: Seems Enfour have a reputation: http://www.pocketables.com/2012/11/enfour-inc-screws-up-big-time-makes-dictionary-app-auto-post-false-accusations-on-users-twitter-accounts.html

Comment: Yeah, I blogged about that when it broke. http://benjaminmayo.co.uk/enfour-embarrasses-pirates-via-twitter

Comment: So, what are we talking about when we say, 'in any way'